# SUM of all numbers until another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get a sum of all the numbers between the SUM formula above it. Since I've got about 5000+ cells, I wanted to just CTRL+H add in the formula to every blank cell. So, is there a formula to automatically get a SUM of everything in the range until the previous SUM formula?

```
|  A1  |
+------+
|  51  |
|  13  |
| SUM1 |
|  11  |
|  14  |
|  21  | 
| SUM2 |
|  15  |
|  15  |
| SUM3 |
```

So Basically I need SUM1 to equal 64 (51+13), SUM2 to equal 46 (11+14+21), SUM3 to equal 30 (15+15), and anything below it to do the same until it reaches the above SUM value.

Answer (score 1):

Select your Data in column A plus one more blank cell, `Goto Special`and choose  `Blanks` and Ok, scroll down to the last empty cell in your selection press and Hold `Ctrl` and left click this cell, release Ctrl and click `Auto Sum` you will have all empty cells filled with the sum of the cells above it.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use **2** columns.  With data in column **A**, starting with **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>"","",SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]